# How to make Eclipse color settings permanent?

Tags: eclipse, themes, editor

I installed Eclipse Luna. I like what the built-in Dark theme does to all the views surrounding the actual text editor. However, I like to use my own color theme Solarized Dark on the editor and furthermore I'm changing a few highlight-box colors in the Editor Annotation settings. I'm able to make all of those configurations just fine. It takes a few minutes however and every time I start Eclipse again all my color settings are back to the default Eclipse Dark Theme, including text editors, highlights and such.

How can I make the aforementioned settings permanent, as in not having to tweak them again every time I start Eclipse?

Comment: How you are starting eclipse. All preferences will be stored under <Workspace_Path>/.metadata folder. If you are staring eclipse with **-clean** option or you deleted this folder then all settings will be assigned to default values.

Comment: It's frustrating, but I posted a workaround in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664179/eclipse-luna-dark-theme-syntax-coloring-resets-how-to-disable

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse,  Window -> preferences ,

in General / appearence /Colors and Fonts

For save changes click first on "Apply" and after "OK"

Comment: That applies the settings but they're gone the next time I start Eclipse. The Eclipse Luna Dark Theme stays but all the other tweaks I made are gone.